# Count JS/CSS file usage

Tags: html, statistics, usage-statistics

I am doing research on usage of JS/CSS files on website. Let me put it this way. I want to (automatically) visit every page on website and make statistics how many times was JS/CSS file used (included into page).

Is there any tool for this or will better to write own script, which will open every anchor link within the same domain, and look into HTML header for JS/CSS file existence?

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but for the record...

I would highly suggest checking out [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/)